# How soluble is uranium in molten iron?

Tags: solutions, solubility, metallurgy, alloy

As I know, uranium and iron simply aren't mixable, which means there are no U-Fe alloys. The Google says, uranium is insoluble in molten iron.

But, if something is "insoluble", it actually means only that there is a very low maximal concentration.

What if we want to mix only 1ppm of U in molten Fe? What if 0.01 ppm? What is the maximal concentration?

Comment: uranium / iron alloys do exist, they have been reported in the inorganic crystallograpic database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Uranium partitioning between liquid iron and silicate melt at
high pressures: implications for uranium solubility in
planetary cores](https://arxiv.org/ftp/astro-ph/papers/0606/0606614.pdf)

> The solubility of U in
>   liquid Fe is in the range of 0.6 to 800 ppm and increases with temperature (T) and
>   pressure (P).

See also [U solubility in Earth’s core](https://arxiv.org/ftp/astro-ph/papers/0606/0606634.pdf) which finds a solubility of 2 ppm at zero pressure (run number 198).

Comment: Hehh, you know the reason, why I asked it! Respect :-)

Comment: There's a difference between solubility and partitioning, which is not clear from the papers you linked to (which weren't peer reviewed I guess). The solubility of U in liquid Fe is almost complete. Partitioning experiments (including the ones you linked to) show that it preferentially goes to the silicate, not the core. Read this [related](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/8214/725) question in ESSE.

Answer (score 7):

At any temperature where the iron is liquid, uranium is also liquid and 100% miscible with it. See [Chen et al.[1]](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnucmat.2015.05.026), from which the diagram below is taken. As with many metal pairs, the liquid phase solubility does not carry over to the solid state, where several intermetallic compounds form.

[image]

**Reference**

1.
Chen, Tianyi;  Smith, Travis; Gigax, Jonathan; Chen, Di; Balerio, Robert; Shao, Lin; Sencer, Bulent; Kennedy, J. (2015). "Intermetallic formation and interdiffusion in diffusion couples made of uranium and single crystal iron." *Journal of Nuclear Materials* **467**, 82-88. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnucmat.2015.05.026.